# How do I remove specific words from a Netezza string?

Tags: netezza

I want to be able to remove specific words from my EARNINGS_CODE column. The words I need to remove are "Earnings" and "Results". I tried using the translate function but that just replaced every letter, not the exact word.

```
SELECT TRANSLATE(EARNINGS_CODE,'EARNINGS','')
FROM PROD_SRC..UWH_OCS_HCM_PAYROLL_COSTING_BIWEEKLY
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```sql
select 
   regexp_replace(earnings_code, 'EARNINGS', '')
from ....
```

For more things to replace, just add to the regex

```sql
select 
   regexp_replace(earnings_code, 'EARNINGS|foo|bar|foobar', '')
from ....
```